# Big IE7 JS bug as well as CSS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, internet-explorer-7

I'm experiencing some IE7 nightmares. The page in question works perfectly well in chrome, FF, and IE8.  In FF, the console show zero errors.

In IE7, though, all hell breaks loose. I can't tell from the builtin IE7 debugger what the issue is.  I've tried removing huge swaths of JS to no avail.

As far as the CSS goes, I corrected it about a week ago and it was all working.  I made some recent changes and it really broke in such a massive way that I'm having a tough time figuring out where to start.

Any help, especially with the js, would be massively appreciated.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Apparently, IE7 is strict with Object syntax. I had an instance like this:

```
{'test':true, 'game':false, }.
```

Apparently that ending comma makes IE 7 expect another key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look yields these blocks:

```
var contentString2=
'<div class="overlay_data">' +

    '<img src="http://nabshack.com/media/original_photos/apt-img5.jpg"/>'

        +
    '<div class="overlay_details">'+

        '<span class="neighborhood">0BR, Brooklyn Heights </span>' +
        '<span class="price">RENT: $500/month </span>' +
        '<span class="price">DAYS POSTED: 15 </span>' +
    '</div>'
'</div>' ;
```

You've got a syntax error after the second-to-last `</div>`.

I'd suggest either breaking it up into chunks, or going one-liner:

```
var contentString2= '<div class="overlay_data"><img src="http://nabshack.com/media/original_photos/apt-img5.jpg"/><div class="overlay_details"><span class="neighborhood">0BR, Brooklyn Heights </span><span class="price">RENT: $500/month </span><span class="price">DAYS POSTED: 15 </span></div></div>';
```

As I don't have IE installed, can you post some screenshots of the hell? It would make debugging a tad bit easier.

Comment: Hey Blender, thanks for that catch.  I couldn't interpret the IE7 debugger at all.  I've add a "+" to concatenate the last two divs. I still have some errors in the page.  Also, I attached a screenshot of the joke that is the html/css rendering

Comment: The Google Map has never loaded properly for me on this page (in IE7).  The rest of the blank space is a new development.  As far as I can tell, the debugger is indicating that I have a syntax error related to olark (a third party widget) and that it expected a "string, identifier, or number" in lines 104, 105, and 109.  I can't see an error in any of those lines and I believe that Olark is fine

Comment: you referring to the olark link? Unfortunately, Olark returns a bunch of responses and the IE7 bugger doesn't play nice in letting me grab the precise one.  I tried removing Olark and I still had the syntax errors in the other three lines.  So maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Just another minor issue: `<img src="http://nabshack.com/media/no-image.png"></img>`. The `<img />` tag is self-closing, like the way I posted it. The correct way would be: `<img src="http://nabshack.com/media/no-image.png" />`. Might screw up IE. Dunno.

Comment: Thanks Blender, I don't know why I did that for some of the img tags.  It wasn't an issue though. I actually just figured out the reason for the JS issues. Apparently, IE7 is strict with Object syntax.  I had an instance like this {'test':true, 'game':false, }.  Apparently that ending comma makes IE 7 expect another key value pair. Interesting

Comment: very annoying indeed. I'll close up this question.  I can figure out the css myself, even if it drives me mad :<.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: I'd leave it open. Others with similar problems will find it useful.

Comment: I meant, I'll give you credit for answering it and post my Solution above